# How to enable authenticated user editing their own record in Drupal

Tags: contacts, user-account

Using CiviCRM 4.6.9 and Drupal.

We need to have a form that allows users to update their own contact data.  While we could do this by creating a specific profile, it seems this is already supported via a connector to Drupal with the form exposed here:

/user/1/edit/name_and_address

This works for administrators, but for regular authenticated users the fields don't show up - although there is a "Save" button down at the bottom.

What do we need to do to enable this for regular authenticated users?

Answer (score 1):

Rob - that tends to work by default on the sites we set up using the 'out of the box' drupal permissions for civi relating to Profiles etc. Is it possible that you have removed some permissions that would have let users submit profiles (don't have them in front of me right now)

Comment: It's possible.  There have been a handful of different people touching this installation and I don't know what all they may have done, good reason or not.

Comment: Allen makes a good point - check the Profile settings

Answer (score 1):

You probably do, but just double checking, do you have the Profile marked in its Civi settings as 'Drupal User Registration' and 'View/Edit Drupal User Account'?

Comment: and wouldn't that have meant user 1 couldn't see it too?